# Django-Oscar Images Error

Tags: python, django, image, django-oscar

I am using Django-Oscar in Mac (mavericks). and everything looks fine but, it doesnt show any image that are correctly uploaded. in the beginning i thought that was a addressing problem but it save the pictures in the right folder. so that is not the problem. then i am trying to install libjpeg, as it was recommended in the installation tutorial.

i have uninstalled Pillow

```
pip uninstall pillow
```

and then i used this command, that i found online to install the libjpeg

```
brew install libjpeg
```

then i installed pillow again and and then everything is the same. it is still not showing any image and the terminal shows that jpeg-8d already installed

could someone help me.
thanks

Comment: Are you getting any error or just the image is not displayed on your webpage. In that case, just add your media folder to urls.py as your media folder may not have public access which could be the reason for image not showing up. 
Add this to urls.py
+ static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)

Comment: yes, posted the full file as an answer, let me know if this works

Comment: thanks Anurag. your post and these 2 extra lines solved  my problem. **from django.conf.urls.static import static

from django.conf import settings**  thanks a lot

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Your media folder may not have public access which could be the reason for image not showing up, add your media folder to the url pattern in urls.py

Check the sample urls.py below

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url
from django.contrib import admin
from oscar.app import application
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
    url(r'^i18n/', include('django.conf.urls.i18n')),
    url(r'', include(application.urls)),
)+ static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

And in your settings.py file, make sure you define media_root and media_url

```
location = lambda x: os.path.join(
os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__)), x)

TEMPLATE_DIRS = (
    location('templates'),
    OSCAR_MAIN_TEMPLATE_DIR,
)
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = location('static')
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
MEDIA_ROOT = location('media')
THUMBNAIL_DEBUG = True
THUMBNAIL_KEY_PREFIX = 'oscar-sandbox'
```

Let me know if these changes work for you

Comment: Thank you, it was of a great help!